# Audio not working with VideoJS and video-hls

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

I am using VideoJS 5.10.2 and Video-contrib-hls 3.0.2 plugin to stream hls videos. Video is working fine. But audio is not working.

HTML code:

```
<video id="video_id" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="268">
   <source src="url/hlsvideo.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

Javascript code:

```
videojs(document.getElementById('video_id'), { 
          "controls": true, 
          "autoplay": false, 
          "preload": "auto"
        }, function() {
          this.play();
        });
```

Comment: What audio codec are you using?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem?

Comment: @JacobPoulRichardt Used aac audio codec. And it worked.

Comment: @Sivakumar Ahh, thanks for the answer, unfortunately that is not an option for us.